# how does margin-left: auto aligns element to the right?

Tags: css

```
    <style>
.box {
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
  <strong>107</strong> Retweets
</div>
```

from my knowledge `margin: auto` is supposed to center an element right?
but what does `margin-left: auto` does to align the child element to the right of the parent.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

With auto, the browser selects a suitable margin to use.

You can think of margin-left: auto as to position the div to the rightmost position possible. This is mentioned in the docs:

> The left margin receives a share of the **unused horizontal space**, as determined mainly by the layout mode that is used.

```css
.box {
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto; 
}
.box2 {
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: auto; 
}
.box3 {
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: auto; 
 margin-left: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <strong>107</strong> Retweets
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <strong>107</strong> Retweets
</div>
<div class="box3">
  <strong>107</strong> Retweets
</div>
```

If both left and right auto are used the element is centered to respect both.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because value `auto` for `margin` tells browser to calculate it.
If you set both `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` then you will see your element centered.

Answer (score 0):

A value of *auto* tells the browser to define the margin for you, [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/).

**margin** property only will center the element if you set both **margin-right** and **margin-left** to **auto**, **or** their short version **margin: 0 auto** (0 top and 0 bottom in this case) **and** set some **width**, without width your auto value has no effect. This property is useful mostly when you are working with older browsers like IE8-9 that don't support flexbox.

Attention point:

- You can't set a margin to center your element vertically if your element position is not absolute, only horizontally.

Comment: "You can't set a margin to center your element vertically, only horizontally.". You can, but only with absolute positioning. e.g. https://jsbin.com/vedojedoju/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: thank you, edited (: @Alohci